# ClangAST Consumer: How to traverse statements, VarDecl, BinaryOperator inside FunctionDecl?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, clang-ast-matchers

Inside the clang AST consumer, I have a walker for FunctionDecl. How to traverse the DeclStmt, Statements, BinaryOperator inside the function declarations. Please suggest with an example.

Answer (score 1):

It's not much information in the question. It would've been more clear with an example of what you want to accomplish with this type of traversal. So, having this much information I can suggest only the most generic solution here.

Clang has a few classes for AST visitors and traversers. *Visitors* are typical representatives of the [pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), while *traversers* are the visitors that also traverse the children of each node. The main *traverser* is **RecursiveASTVisitor**. You can read about it in the [manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html) or in the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html).

Here is an example:

```cpp
class Traverser : public RecursiveASTVisitor<Traverser> {
public:
  bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *D) {
    D->dump();
    return true;
  }

  bool VisitDeclStmt(DeclStmt *DS) {
    DS->dump();
    return true;
  }

  bool VisitBinaryOperator(BinaryOperator *BO) {
    BO->dump();
    return true;
  }
};
```

This solution will visit ANY function declarations, declaration statements and binary expressions. If you want more tuned approach you can tweak traversal by redefining *Traverse** methods and so on. If this is not the case, you always can implement your own *traverser* using [StmtVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1StmtVisitor.html), [DeclVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DeclVisitor.html), [TypeVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TypeVisitor.html), and [TypeLocVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TypeLocVisitor.html).

I hope this information is useful and will be helpful for you. Happy hacking with Clang!

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
Example I wanted to use is:
int foo ( int a, int b)
{
a++;
return a;
}

Output( something like this detail i wanted to know):
used_paramter->a
a++;

unused parameter->b

Comment: Does it answer your question? If so, would you mind marking this answer as accepted?
If no, please clarify what are you looking for and I'll try to alter my answer :)

Comment: Stackoverflow way is to update your question with this request and I will update my answer, so it's easier for other people to understand what's going on.

Comment: I already have VisitFunctionDecl methods. How can i implement my own traverser using StmtVisitor, DeclVisitor, TypeVisitor, and TypeLocVisitor. Any example please. Mainly I want to do liveness analysis of each expressions, statements, etc as shown in AST dump like -CompoundStmt, UnaryOperator, DeclRefExpr. Can i access all these details through the code and record the output accordingly.